# Consultas assicronas ao mysql no nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, assincronismo, promises

Olá, tenho um código em nodejs com banco de dados mysql. em uma das rotas referentes ao path(trajeto) preciso buscar todos as leituras de 3 sensores(cada sensor é uma tabela) que possuem o campo trajeto_id igual ao id do trajeto, eu utilizava um modelo de promisses encadeadas mas acabei mudando para um modelo com await como o que segue abaixo

```js
path.gps = await sql_op.select(null, targets, 'gps')
path.giroscopio = await sql_op.select(null, targets, 'giroscopio')
path.acelerometro = await sql_op.select(null, targets, 'acelerometro')
```

as funções de busca no mysql estão implementada e funcionam corretamente, cada uma delas retorna uma promisse que resolve quando a busca é concluída, minha duvida está em como otimizar essa consulta, visto que tenho que fazer os 3 selects para pode exibir os dados na pagina

Comment: Boa tarde, uma forma de otimizar é criar apenas um select já que compartilham o campo trajeto_id, nesse caso tu terá apenas uma promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode aninhar em um `array` de promessas e depois utilizar o [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) para executá-las em paralelo em conjunto com o `await` para aguardar a execução de todos:

```
// ...
const promessas = [
  sql_op.select(null, targets, 'gps'),
  sql_op.select(null, targets, 'giroscopio'),
  sql_op.select(null, targets, 'acelerometro'),
];

const [gps, giroscopio, acelerometro] = await Promise.all(promessas);

path.gps = gps;
path.giroscopio = giroscopio;
path.acelerometro = acelerometro;
// ...
```

**Observação:** Nesse trecho que foi fornecido essa é única alteração que me vem a mente, porém se você fornecer a implementação da função `sql_op.select` posso tentar melhorar também nesse sentido.

> [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
>
> O método [`Promise.all(iterable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) retorna uma `promise` que resolve quando todas as `promises` no argumento iterável forem resolvidas.

Comment: Obrigado, a consulta em si, creio que esteja bem escrita. estou usando o modulo mysql com um pool de 10 conexões